# Form/PHP script clears the form after submission as desired in Edge, Submits but not clearing form in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Why does this PHP/Form submit and clear in Edge, but a form submit in Chrome and Firefox is not clearing the form after submit.

End result will be Edge submits the form, pops up a success message then clears the data from the form. Both in Chrome and Firefox, it submits the data but the success message and the form does not clear, allowing multiple submissions of the same form.

Here is the Form:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/haydon.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/forms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="../bin/Mailhandler.php">
        <div class="success">Contact form submitted!
            <br><strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <label class="name">
                <input type="text" value="Name:"><span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            </label>
            <label class="email">
                <input type="text" value="E-mail:"><span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            </label>
            <label class="phone">
                <input type="tel" value="Phone:"><span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            </label>
            <label class="message">
                <textarea>Message:</textarea><span class="error">*The message is too short.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
            </label>
            <div class="buttons-wrapper"><a class="button" data-type="reset">Clear</a><a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
//SMTP server settings  
$host = "smtp.blanked.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "smtpform@blanked.com";
$password = "Blanked";
$messageBody = "";

if($_POST['name']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST['email']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}else{
    $headers = '';
}

if($_POST['state']!='false'){       
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST['phone']!='false'){       
    $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}   

if($_POST['fax']!='false'){     
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST['message']!='false'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}

if($host=="" or $username=="" or $password==""){
    $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["owner_email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
            }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }

}else{  
    require_once 'Mail.php';

    $to = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $subject = 'A message from your site visitor ' . $_POST["name"];
    $headers = array (
    'From' => 'From:' . $_POST["owner_email"] . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n",
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

    $smtp = Mail::factory(
                'smtp',
                array (
                    'host' => $host,
                    'port' => $port,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $messageBody);

    try{
        if(PEAR::isError($mail)){
            echo $mail->getMessage();
            }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
        }catch(Exception $mail){
        echo $mail->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
}   
?>
```

Here is the forms.js

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.forms = function (o) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var th = $(this),
            _ = th.data('forms') || {
                errorCl: 'error',
                emptyCl: 'empty',
                invalidCl: 'invalid',
                notRequiredCl: 'notRequired',
                successCl: 'success',
                successShow: '4000',
                mailHandlerURL: 'http://www.blankeddomain.co.uk/bin/Mailhandler.php',
                ownerEmail: '',
                stripHTML: true,
                smtpMailServer: 'localhost',
                targets: 'input,textarea',
                controls: 'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                validate: true,
                rx: {
                    ".name": {
                        rx: /^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,
                        target: 'input'
                    },
                    ".state": {
                        rx: /^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,
                        target: 'input'
                    },
                    ".email": {
                        rx: /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,
                        target: 'input'
                    },
                    ".phone": {
                        rx: /^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,
                        target: 'input'
                    },
                    ".fax": {
                        rx: /^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,
                        target: 'input'
                    },
                    ".message": {
                        rx: /.{20}/,
                        target: 'textarea'
                    }
                },
                preFu: function () {
                    _.labels.each(function () {
                        var label = $(this),
                            inp = $(_.targets, this),
                            defVal = inp.val(),
                            trueVal = (function () {
                                var tmp = inp.is('input') ? (tmp = label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/), !! tmp && !! tmp[1] && tmp[1]) : inp.html()
                                return defVal == '' ? defVal : tmp
                            })()
                            trueVal != defVal && inp.val(defVal = trueVal || defVal)
                            label.data({
                                defVal: defVal
                            })
                            inp
                                .bind('focus', function () {
                                    inp.val() == defVal && (inp.val(''), _.hideEmptyFu(label), label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur', function () {
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if (_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal), _.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('keyup', function () {
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl) && _.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.' + _.errorCl + ',.' + _.emptyCl).css({
                                display: 'block'
                            }).hide()
                    })
                    _.success = $('.' + _.successCl, _.form).hide()
                },
                isRequired: function (el) {
                    return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                },
                isValid: function (el) {
                    var ret = true
                    $.each(_.rx, function (k, d) {
                        if (el.is(k))
                            ret = d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())
                    })
                    return ret
                },
                isEmpty: function (el) {
                    var tmp
                    return (tmp = el.find(_.targets).val()) == '' || tmp == el.data('defVal')
                },
                validateFu: function (el) {
                    el.each(function () {
                        var th = $(this),
                            req = _.isRequired(th),
                            empty = _.isEmpty(th),
                            valid = _.isValid(th)

                            if (empty && req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if (!empty)
                                if (valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                    })
                },
                getValFromLabel: function (label) {
                    var val = $('input,textarea', label).val(),
                        defVal = label.data('defVal')
                        return label.length ? val == defVal ? 'nope' : val : 'nope'
                },
                submitFu: function () {
                    _.validateFu(_.labels)
                    if (!_.form.has('.' + _.invalidCl).length)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: _.mailHandlerURL,
                            data: {
                                name: _.getValFromLabel($('.name', _.form)),
                                email: _.getValFromLabel($('.email', _.form)),
                                phone: _.getValFromLabel($('.phone', _.form)),
                                fax: _.getValFromLabel($('.fax', _.form)),
                                state: _.getValFromLabel($('.state', _.form)),
                                message: _.getValFromLabel($('.message', _.form)),
                                owner_email: _.ownerEmail,
                                stripHTML: _.stripHTML
                            },
                            success: function () {
                                _.showFu()
                            }
                        })
                },
                showFu: function () {
                    _.success.slideDown(function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            _.success.slideUp()
                            _.form.trigger('reset')
                        }, _.successShow)
                    })
                },
                controlsFu: function () {
                    $(_.controls, _.form).each(function () {
                        var th = $(this)
                        th
                            .bind('click', function () {
                                _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                return false
                            })
                    })
                },
                showErrorFu: function (label) {
                    label.find('.' + _.errorCl).slideDown()
                },
                hideErrorFu: function (label) {
                    label.find('.' + _.errorCl).slideUp()
                },
                showEmptyFu: function (label) {
                    label.find('.' + _.emptyCl).slideDown()
                    _.hideErrorFu(label)
                },
                hideEmptyFu: function (label) {
                    label.find('.' + _.emptyCl).slideUp()
                },
                init: function () {
                    _.form = _.me
                    _.labels = $('label', _.form)

                    _.preFu()

                    _.controlsFu()

                    _.form
                        .bind('submit', function () {
                            if (_.validate)
                                _.submitFu()
                            else
                                _.form[0].submit()
                            return false
                        })
                        .bind('reset', function () {
                            _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)
                            _.labels.each(function () {
                                var th = $(this)
                                _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                            })
                        })
                    _.form.trigger('reset')
                }
            }
        _.me || _.init(_.me = th.data({
            forms: _
        }))
        typeof o == 'object' && $.extend(_, o)
    })
}
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#contact-form').forms({
        ownerEmail: 'blanked@domain.co.uk'
    })
})
```

Any direction or advice from other eyes would be appreciated at this point.

Comment: That's A LOT of code, is it all relevant to the question? Please read about creating a [mcve] (With an emphasis on **Minimal**)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was dreading posting it but I have hit a wall. I have shortened the HTML. forms.js and Mailhandler.php I'm not sure what I would be able to lose to make it shorter without missing any code as both of them are relevant. Sorry if that doesn't help.